# How to display MD5 Hash results on output window? Java

Tags: java, hash, jframe, md5

On the hash example it displays the output in the console. How can I implement this into my application so that it will hash the text input then display the hash where it says "hash to appear here!!"

Comment: https://s32.postimg.org/eb609f0dh/hasher1.png

Answer (score 0):

Using your own example, create an Utility Hashing class, with a static method like this...

```
public class MD5Util {
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "MD5";
    public static String getHash(String text){
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            md.update(text.getBytes());
            byte[] byteData = md.digest();
            StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
            for(byte bd : byteData){
                String hex = Integer.toHexString(bd & 0xff);
                if(hex.length() == 1)
                    hexString.append(0);
                hexString.append(hex);
            }
            return hexString.toString();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MD5Util.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then, call that static method and set the result into the Label field, like this...

```
hashValueLabel.setText(MD5Util.getHash(textInputLabel.getText()));
```